# Realtimesync: MTP Protocol does not support directory monitoring on Android

Tags: android, sync, mtp, realtimesync

I have a Samsung J7 Prime running Marshmallow. I tried to synchronize one folder of the phone with another folder on my PC using FreeFileSync and it worked fine. Now, I wanted to make the synchronization automatic everytime when I insert the phone to my computer.
OS: Windows 8.1 Pro (64-bit)
1. I saved a batch file of the configuration I used in the mirror syncronization in FFS.
2. I opened realtimesync and drag-and-dropped the batch file. Now I wanted that the two folders be in sync automatically.
3. Clicked on "Start".

RESULT: Error: MTP Protocol does not support directory monitoring:
"mtp:\Galaxy J7 Prime\Phone\DCIM"

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: It might help if you said what operating system your PC is using. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. Note that there are tags for the  most common OSs.